# How can I pass text to summarise() in shiny

Tags: r, dplyr, eval, summarize, nse

I'm building a shinyapp. I try to save the functions user selected as char into to a `data.frame()`, and then use `paste()` to generate something like "n = n(), sum = sum(value), mean = mean(value)" or shorter, and finally pass to summarise()
I tried the `enquote()` and `eval(parse())`, all failed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
      wellPanel(
        selectInput("data_groupby", label = "group_by", choices = c(Choose = "", "group", "sameple", "var"), selected = c("group", "var"), multiple = TRUE),
        actionButton("data_groupby_ok", "click here to group_by"),
        selectInput("data_summarise_fun", "Function", choices = c(Choose = "", "n", "sum", "mean")),
        actionButton("data_summarise_add", "Summarise"),
        h4("paras to be passed to summarise():"),
        verbatimTextOutput("summarise_paras")
      )
    ),
    column(width = 3,
      h4("data:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("data")
    ),
    column(width = 3,
      h4("data_summarised:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("data_summarised")
    ),
    column(width = 3,
      h4("data_desired (if add 3 functions):"),
      verbatimTextOutput("data_desired")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  aggr <- reactiveValues(
    data = NULL,
    summarise_paras = data.frame(column = character()),
    data_grouped = NULL,
    data_summarised = NULL,
    data_desired = NULL
  )

  set.seed(50)
  aggr$data <- data.frame(
    group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 6),
    sample = rep(c(paste0("A_", 1:3), paste0("B_", 1:3), paste0("C_", 1:3)), each = 2),
    var = rep(c("height", "weight"), times = 9),
    value = runif(18, min = 0, max = 1)
  )

  aggr$data_desired <- data.frame(
    group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 6),
    sample = rep(c(paste0("A_", 1:3), paste0("B_", 1:3), paste0("C_", 1:3)), each = 2),
    var = rep(c("height", "weight"), times = 9),
    value = runif(18, min = 0, max = 1)
  ) %>%
    group_by(group, var) %>% summarise(n = n(), sum = sum(value), mean = mean(value))

  observeEvent(input$data_groupby_ok, {
    groupby <- input$data_groupby
    aggr$data_grouped <- aggr$data %>% group_by(across(all_of(groupby)))
    disable("data_groupby")
  })

  observe({
    toggleState("data_summarise_add", nchar(input$data_summarise_fun) >0)
  })

  observeEvent(input$data_summarise_add, {

    tryCatch({
      fun <- input$data_summarise_fun

      if (fun == "n") {
        para <- "n = n()"
      } else if (fun == "sum") {
        para <- "sum = sum(value)"
      } else if (fun == "mean") {
        para <- "mean = mean(value)"
      }
      aggr$summarise_paras <- aggr$summarise_paras %>%
                              filter(column != para) %>%
                              bind_rows(data.frame(column = para))
      paras <- paste(aggr$summarise_paras$column, collapse = ",")
      aggr$data_summarised <- aggr$data_grouped %>% summarise(enquote(paras))

      reset("data_summarise_fun")
    }, error = function(e) {
      showNotification(paste(e$message), type = "error", duration = 5)
    })
  })

  output$data <- renderPrint({print(aggr$data)})
  output$summarise_paras <- renderPrint({print(aggr$summarise_paras)})
  output$data_summarised <- renderPrint({print(aggr$data_summarised)})
  output$data_desired <- renderPrint({print(aggr$data_desired)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My desired output is `aggr$data_desired`, which was printed in my shiny example

Comment: I think this might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  *Why* do you want to define what `summarise` does using a string?  Because you want to have control over what it does, in a function or app, perhaps?

Comment: yes! I want use it in Shiny. Save the functions as char into to a `data.frame(paras = character())`, and then use `paste(., collapse = ",")` to generate something like "n = n(), sum = sum(value), mean = mean(value)", and finally pass to `summarise()`

Comment: I suspect @Mark is correct when they say there is no way to do what you want in the way you want to do it.  So, based on your (OP's) previous comment, I think you may want to allow users of your app to select some grouping columns, select an analysis column, select some summary statistics and then give them the output based on their selections.  Am I close?  if so, then this most definitely is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Please describe how you want your app to behave.

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. I've re-edited my question with a minimal example of the problem I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that (presumably) you want the values to be things like "n = 10, sum = -0.369, mean = -0.036987", but what you have written isn't that - it's bad because it's not valid R code (you can't just write `x = 1, y = 2` in R, you will get the error `Error: unexpected ',' in "x = 1,"`, but also because equals is for assignment, and you don't seem to want to assign `n()` to the variable `n`.

One option is using [glue](https://glue.tidyverse.org/):

```
data |> summarise(val = glue::glue("n = {n()}, sum = {sum(value)}, mean = {mean(value)}"), .by = c(group, var))
```

Output:

```
   group var                                                          val
1      A   a n = 10, sum = -0.369871614091487, mean = -0.0369871614091487
2      A   b   n = 10, sum = -4.90551745324375, mean = -0.490551745324375
3      A   c   n = 10, sum = -4.04729937846017, mean = -0.404729937846017
4      A   d   n = 10, sum = -2.54372850319173, mean = -0.254372850319173
5      B   c   n = 10, sum = 0.936866512219415, mean = 0.0936866512219415
6      B   d   n = 10, sum = -3.34912487194284, mean = -0.334912487194284
7      B   a n = 10, sum = -0.341116609361569, mean = -0.0341116609361569
8      B   b   n = 10, sum = -3.18225275070246, mean = -0.318225275070246
9      C   a   n = 10, sum = -4.74290766135976, mean = -0.474290766135976
10     C   b   n = 10, sum = 0.112798793892494, mean = 0.0112798793892494
11     C   c   n = 10, sum = -1.44746005504636, mean = -0.144746005504636
12     C   d   n = 10, sum = -1.31363366405953, mean = -0.131363366405953
13     D   c     n = 10, sum = -3.3104100896434, mean = -0.33104100896434
14     D   d     n = 10, sum = 1.38864716115738, mean = 0.138864716115738
15     D   a     n = 10, sum = 6.04682327356391, mean = 0.604682327356391
16     D   b   n = 10, sum = -2.40214704657337, mean = -0.240214704657337
17     E   a   n = 10, sum = -2.66630215861559, mean = -0.266630215861559
18     E   b n = 10, sum = -0.889225624753177, mean = -0.0889225624753177
19     E   c   n = 10, sum = -6.39670148391452, mean = -0.639670148391452
20     E   d   n = 10, sum = -4.79912286801664, mean = -0.479912286801664
```

Comment: Not really the result I was looking for, its structure should be like result1, in the most common way

Comment: thanks for telling me that now, after I had already written the answer lol

Comment: I think the essence of my feedback of why your code doesn't work is the same. Putting the entire thing in plain text and then running eval(parse()) on it works though

Comment: I'm really sorry for the incomplete question, I was trying to skip over describing too much, but instead I've created more trouble

Comment: @toxin it's okay- if you could answer Limey's question, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MWE that I think achieves your goal but takes a different approach to yours.  I discard the intermediate data frame and use the values of Shiny widgets to produce the summary table.  The only tricky piece is the use of `!!as.symbol()`, which is needed to convert Shiny's input strings to the `tidy-select`ed symbols that are needed by the tidyverse.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "analysisVar", 
    "Analysis variable:", 
    choices = names(mtcars),
    selected = "mpg"
  ),
  selectInput(
    "groupVar", 
    "Group variable:", 
    choices = names(mtcars),
    selected = "cyl"
  ),
  selectInput(
    "statistics", 
    "Summary statistics", 
    choices = c("mean", "min", "max", "median"), 
    multiple = TRUE,
    selected = "mean"
  ),
  dataTableOutput("results")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  summaryStats <- reactive({
    req(input$groupVar, input$analysisVar)
    
    mtcars %>% 
      group_by(!!as.symbol(input$groupVar)) %>% 
      summarise(
        across(
          !!as.symbol(input$analysisVar), 
          .fns = list(mean = mean, min = min, max = max, median = median),
          .names = "{.fn}"
        ),
        .groups = "drop"
      ) %>% 
      select(input$groupVar, input$statistics)
  })
  
  output$results <- renderDataTable({ summaryStats() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```